.NET MAUI Windows App Fails to Run After Successful AOT Compilation
Here's a refined version of the question focused on .NET MAUI targeting Windows:

Title:
.NET MAUI Windows App Fails to Run After Successful AOT Compilation

Body:
I am developing a .NET MAUI application targeting Windows. The application compiles successfully with Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compilation, but it fails to run.
Steps I Followed:

Enabled AOT compilation in the project settings for the Windows target.
Compiled the application using the following command:
dotnet build -t:Run -f net7.0-windows --configuration Release  


Attempted to launch the application on my development machine.

Observations:

The build completes successfully without any errors.
When I try to run the application, [describe what happens: crashes, blank window, no response, etc.].
No meaningful logs or error messages are displayed in the output.

Troubleshooting Steps:

Verified that the application runs as expected in Debug mode (without AOT enabled).
Ensured that all dependencies and configurations match the requirements for a Windows-targeted MAUI app.
Checked .NET SDK and Windows development environment for compatibility issues.
Tried enabling verbose logging to diagnose the issue, but the logs do not provide clarity on what might be causing the failure.

Environment Details:

OS: Windows [version, e.g., 11 Pro Build 22621]
.NET SDK Version: [e.g., 7.0.x, 6.0.x]
MAUI Version: [e.g., .NET MAUI 7.0.x]
Target Framework: net7.0-windows
Development Environment: [e.g., Visual Studio 2022 v17.x]

Questions:

Are there specific configurations or prerequisites for enabling and running AOT in .NET MAUI for Windows?
What debugging tools or techniques can I use to identify and resolve runtime issues with AOT?
Could this issue be related to dependencies or libraries that are not compatible with AOT on Windows?

Any help in resolving this issue or pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Would you like me to clarify any points or tailor this further?

Look in the Windows event log, Application section, for an exception notification.  And look here

Did you try to update the .net sdk version from 7.0 to 8.0?
